# Create a folder shortcut in the Ubuntu server terminal

Tags: shortcuts

I have a little problem. I want to create a folder shortcut but I can't do that easily because the system doesn't have any GUI environment so if some angel could tell me how can I create a folder shortcut or a command executer simply.

Please note this is for an FTP server and ssh server so I can access my /var/www/html/ folder without access to the others folders so if someone help me I will be very grateful.

Answer (score 1):

You only need to execute this command:
`ln -s /var/www/html /path/to/your/new/link`

This will create a symbolic link (a simple "shortcut") from `/path/to/your/new/link` to the destination `/var/www/html`.

Comment: thanks, it worked, thank you for the simplicity

Comment: Please don't forget to accept an answer. It doesn't matter in this case, but it'll help other people in case there are multiple answers to a question.